# how to get icManufacturerCode of NFC tag in iOS

Tags: swift, ios11, core-nfc

Using CoreNFC I want to read icMenufecturerCode of NFC Tag. According to Apple documentation NFCISO15693Tag has property named icManufacturerCode that can be read as:

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    for tag in tags {
        let rfidTag = tag as! NFCISO15693Tag
        print("- Is available: \(rfidTag.isAvailable)")
        print("- Type: \(rfidTag.type)")
        print("- IC Manufacturer Code: \(rfidTag.icManufacturerCode)")
        print("- IC Serial Number: \(rfidTag.icSerialNumber)")
        print("- Identifier: \(rfidTag.identifier)")
    }
}
```

But I am getting confused .. is it the right tag reader session or there is some other way to read manufacturer Id of NFC Tag in iOS 11. 
In iOS 11 we have `NFCNDEFReaderSession`. I implemented code using `NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate` but those methods doesn't provide any way to read icManufacturerCode. Is it fine to replace that code with `NFCReaderSessionDelegate` methods?? 
And what type of tag will  `NFCReaderSession` read?

I know it is not a good and clear question but my confusion is something weird. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for iOS11 are related to the signature of classes and protocols on the part of Apple (protocol `NFCTag` have become enum for iOS13, if I don't confuse). However, you can use this code and it should work for all versions of iOS11+

```
extension YourViewController: __NFCReaderSessionDelegate {

    func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCReaderSession) {

    }

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCReaderSession, didDetect tags: [__NFCTag]) {
        for tag in tags {
            let rfidTag = tag as! NFCISO15693Tag
            print("- Is available: \(rfidTag.isAvailable)")
            print("- Type: \(rfidTag.type)")
            print("- IC Manufacturer Code: \(rfidTag.icManufacturerCode)")
            print("- IC Serial Number: \(rfidTag.icSerialNumber)")
            print("- Identifier: \(rfidTag.identifier)")
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 required methods and one optional (it's from Obj-C), just to get `icManufacturerCode`.

[According to documentation of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcreadersession-mnv?language=objc)

> use an instance of NFCNDEFReaderSession or NFCTagReaderSession. Only
>   one reader session of any type can be active in the system at a time

Comment: thanks again .. Just one more thing, Can u please tell me what type of data is returned by rfidTag.icManufacturerCode ?? A String or a number, Is it hex or decimal ??

Comment: in my example - it's a reader session for detecting ISO7816, ISO15693, FeliCa, and MIFARE tags. If you want to work with detection NFC tags with NDEF messages - use `NFCNDEFReaderSession`. `icManufacturerCode` is `var icManufacturerCode: Int { get }`

Comment: Ok its Int as I can see in Apple developer site..So, I need reverse hex of icMenufacturerCode in my project.. for this should I convert this int into hexadecimal and then reverse it ???

Comment: `let hex = String(icManufacturerCode, radix: 16)`- it's converter

Comment: If I want to use NFCNDEFReaderSession then how can I get icManufacturerCode of the NFC Tag??

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to get it for iOS11

Comment: I think it is not possible to get it in NFCNDEFReaderSession.